# What is the probability of flipping tail heads combination on two coins?

Tags: probability

To find probability I should divide number of desired outcomes by total number of outcomes. So in this question I want TH (tail heads) combination out of two coins.  What is the right way to get that probability and why?

It seems that there is three ways to calculate that probability. First one: desired outcome(TH)/possible outcomes(TT,HH,TH)=1/3. Second one: TH/(TT,HH,TH,HT)=1/4. From the last equation – if order doesn’t matter to me (TH=HT)  - probability would be equal to 1/2((TH,HT)/(TT,HH,TH,HT)). That problem arise from the fact that there is no way to distinguish TH from HT.  How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different way to think about this. If $TH = HT$, then the outcomes we want are $\{TH, HT\}$ and the set of all outcomes is $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$. So the ratio is $2/4 \ 1/2$.

The first formula: $$\text{desired outcome}(TH)/ \text{possible outcomes}(TT,HH,TH)=1/3$$ is just wrong, since $HT$ as a possible outcome is missed. It's not like the coins magically change and you lose a $HT$ occuring in nature. Rather, *what you consider a desirable outcome* changes.

Comment: I was doing experiment 34 times. Results -  TT(0.26) HH(0.29) TH(0.44). You a right))

Answer (score 1):

The rule that

> the probability of an positive outcome is the number of positive outcomes divided by the number of all outcomes

is only true **if all outcomes are equally likely**.

If you consider the outcomes $TH$ and $HT$ as equal, then the probability of the outcome $TH$ is no longer the same as the probability of the outcome $TT$, therefore, you cannot use the rule above. Therefore, the result $\frac13$ is wrong.